# JPA: Fixed value join columns in collection of elements

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to reduce the total number of similar tables in my database by using a fixed identifier in each join.

Currently my entity class looks like this:

```
public class Group {

    [...]

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "group_admins",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @OrderBy
    private Set<String> admins = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "group_moderators",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @OrderBy
    private Set<String> moderators = new LinkedHashSet<>();     

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "group_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @OrderBy
    private Set<String> users = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    [...]

}
```

And this causes it to create 1+3=4 tables. 3 of them share the exact same columns. Now I would like to reduce this to 1+1=2 tables like that: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_05/ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins.html

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "person",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "person.type", referencedColumnName="'user'")
            })
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @OrderBy
    private Set<String> users = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Which I expect to create a table like this:

- Person

  - group_id: int
  - type: varchar [either of: 'user', 'moderator', 'admin']
  - name: varchar

But I always end up with an exception similar to this one:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: 'user' in group
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:858) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1611) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:810) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:735) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
```

It does not even try to execute the SQL.

I also tried @DescriminatorColumn, but that does not even apply to attributes.

Is there a way to do that without using an extra entity/embeddable for that?

I use

- Java 8
- Hibernate 5.2.12
- Spring Boot

Comment: From the example you gave, you are referencing a column named `'user'`, with the unnecessary quotes. Try and remove them as a start, to see if it helps solve your problem. Moreover, it seems kinda strange that you have a `@CollectionTable` annotation and a `@Column` annotation on the same `Set`.

Comment: @DamCx The @ Column is ok. This is where the String gets persisted.

Comment: `'user'` does not reference a column, it should reference a fixed value: `JOIN person p ON g.id = p.group_id AND p.type = 'user'`

Comment: @RobertNiestroj On the same Set ?? What then would be the interpretation from Hibernate?

Comment: I just want hibernate/jpa to add a discriminator, so that I can reuse a table for more than one collection of element (that always contain the same attributes).

Comment: Shared join tables (what you would need when not wanting to create a different entity) is not part of the JPA API. Some JPA providers may support it (e.g http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_shared_join ) but that is not part of the JPA spec.

Comment: You have to create a set of classes with `@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")` and the different sub classes with some `@DiscriminatorValue("xxx")`

Comment: Which is not possible for `String`s and would also somehow defeat the purpose of avoiding to create new entity classes. It looks like I have to create a full fletched entity/embeddable class.